# Joomla 3.X - Remove tooltip script from header?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, tooltip

I'm trying to remove unwanted scripts from my custom joomla template header, which I've managed to remove everything except for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function()
                {
                    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({});
                });
  </script>
```

I've searched for hours and I've tried numerous things to get it removed, but I can't seem to get rid of it. Here's what I've done to remove the other scripts I don't want (for anyone else who has this issue):

```
# unset frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework',false);
JHtml::_('jquery.framework',false);

# unset scripts
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);
```

If someone could help me remove that tooltip javascript, that would be fantastic. Oh and I don't want to touch the core files, so I'm trying to remove it from the template index.php file itself.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a clear fix for this issue in 3.4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some component/Module/Plugin is calling the function JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip'). and that function add your code.

you can do:

The dirty way: go to libraries\cms\html\bootstrap.php and change the file at the method tooltip(). but remember it's a core file so upgrade can overide your changes.

The clean way, find the component    that adds this code and remove or change it.

Good Luck

Comment: Components calling JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip'); (of which there are lots) will also cause this code to be added.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to manually parse `$doc->_script`.  The `$doc->_scripts` array contains scripts that are linked to another source while `$doc->_script` is for script declarations like the tooltip one.

Comment: I've tried using $doc->_script, but it doesn't pickup the tooltip code - the array returns empty.

Comment: Stepping through the code, starting at JHtmlBootstrap::tooltip() where that JS snippet is generated, you'll see that the snippet is set to $doc->_script.  Why you're getting an empty array is beyond me at the moment, but you're looking at the right place.

Comment: I've found where it adds the code, but I don't want to hack the core to remove it. I've also tried echoing out the $doc->_script array in the header and footer of the template index file, but still get nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get rid of the embedded javascript using this code in my template's index.php file:

```
unset($this->_script['text/javascript']);
```

disclaimer: I am not a PHP developer, so use above code at your own risk :)

Answer (score 3):

At the end of your web root index.php (not template, http://domain.com/index.php) replace the $app->execute(); line with the following:

```
// Start the output buffer.
ob_start();

// Execute the application.
$app->execute();

// Get buffer
$buffer = ob_get_clean();

// Change HTML
$buffer = str_replace('<script type="text/javascript">'.chr(10).'jQuery(document).ready(function(){'.chr(10).'  jQuery(\'.hasTooltip\').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});'.chr(10).'});'.chr(10).'  </script>','',$buffer);

// Output buffer
echo($buffer);
```

Note that you would need to use the **EXACT** HTML that's being created by the module.  This is what my module is creating, yours could be slightly different.

In addition to doing HTML rewrites like this, you could also tidy the output, remove links to modules, etc.

I also use this for doing things like changing the copyright year on a website.  In a module position, I reference the current year as "{year}" and then I add another str_replace which does the following:

```
$buffer = str_replace('{year}',date('Y'),$buffer);
```

Bingo, always shows the current year.

Enjoy...

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Joomla documents](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks), 2 things to consider:

a) In the below code, you're actually enabling/including bootstrap and jquery:

```
# unset frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework',false);// including bootstrap!
JHtml::_('jquery.framework',false);// including jquery!
```

When bootstrap is enabled, joomla automatically enables jquery, and if joomla enabled jquery, joomla automatically enables tooltip.

Just don't call these functions. The `unset` you used will remove bootstrap and jquery correctly:

```
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js']);
```

b) if the tooltip script is still included, it's probably inserted by `JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');` somewhere in the used component.

Lastly, never never never modify Joomla core files. it's a worst-practice.

**PS.**
For those who mentioned that the tooltip script is inserted but they don't find it in the `$doc`, that's because the `$doc` doesn't contain inline scripts.

Comment: The `$doc` does contain the inline scripts too. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have already meet this issue, I am using Joomla 3. If it is your case then you can solve it by doing this :
Joomla 3 comes with jQuery on board, so by adding Joomla yourself, this may generate the issue.
Also make sure you include your jQuery over `<jdoc:include type="head" />`. If you necessary wants to include it. But I do not recommend this.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was building a Joomla template/site with only HTML5, CSS3 and some small jQuery plugins for effects. It was unworthy of including heavy Bootstrap just to show some tooltips which I also didn't use at all.

Althought I already unset media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js from JDocument but these lines of code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
});
```

were still appended by libraries/cms/html/bootstrap.php. So I got error "function tooltip not found".

I solved that by adding an empty function to my template's JS file.

```
jQuery.fn.tooltip = function (option) { };
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Joomla Plugin available which unsets Bootstrap and also removes the tooltip function snippet wich is inserted by `JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');` somewhere in any component.

[See here: Disable Bootstrap Plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/dd-disable-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Create a system plugin with the follow code.

The First foreach loop `unset`s the `.js` file(s) added to the head. And the next foreach loop `unset`s the `js` code injected inside `<script>` tags.

There are two separate properties containing the scripts the `_script` & `_scripts`

```
public function onBeforeCompileHead() {
    // Front end
    if ($this->app instanceof JApplicationSite) {
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

        $search = array(
//                'jquery',
//                'caption.js',
//                'bootstrap.min.js',
//                'core.js',
//                'keepalive.js',
//                'punycode.js',
//                'validate.js',
//                'calendar.js',
//                'calendar-setup.js',
//                'mootools-more.js',
//                'modal.js',
//                'ajax-chosen.min.js',
//                'tabs-state.js',
//                'frontediting.js',
//                'html5fallback.js',
//                'jui/js/bootstrap.min.js',
//                'jquery.min.js',
            'jui/js/',
            'system/js/',
//                'text/javascript'
        );
        foreach ($doc->_scripts as $key => $script) {
            foreach ($search as $findme) {
                if (stristr($key, $findme) !== false) {
                    unset($doc->_scripts[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($doc->_script as $key => $script) {
            if (stristr($key, 'text/javascript') !== false) {
                unset($doc->_script[$key]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```