# Joomla 3, disable tooltips using javascript

Tags: javascript, joomla

I would like to remove all tooltips - but only when viewed on mobile devices.

I am using javascript to check for windowsize (on load and on re-zize), which is working fine - but I cant seem to figure out how to turn off the tooltips, using javascript.

Is there a tooltip.stop() - or something else that can turn off the tooltips (and possibly turn back on, on resize?)

The reason for my request is that I have tooltips on some of my buttons, and apparently the tooltip fires on first tap, instead of just triggering the button. (The button should fire a javascript). 
Only the second tap fires the button javascript. Which is a little annoying.

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725166/joomla-3-x-remove-tooltip-script-from-header

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to remove the script. I just want to disable tooltips, on event. (on click) and then re-enable on event. I am looking for a javascript call to disable and re-enable tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to remove tooltips in Joomla's pagination. I targeted the links which have the class "pagination" and removed all their event handlers with:

```
jQuery(".pagination a").off() ;
```

You could doubtless find a selector to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, as the script inserted by Joomla keys off the class name `hasTooltip`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".pagenav").removeClass('hasTooltip') ;
});
```